# (Vue) Reading parent's props in slot content

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-props, vuejs-slots

I have a table component that takes a 'variant' prop which simply dictates some css styles to apply. I use it as follows:

```
<BaseTable :variant="'with_background'" :columns="[{ name: 'Datum' }, { name: 'Bedrag', alignment: 'right' }, { name: 'Verkoper' }, { name: 'Status' }]">
  <BaseTableRow v-for="(pastOrder, index) in pastOrders" :key="index" :variant="'with_background'">
    <BaseTableCell :variant="'with_background'">{{ pastOrder.date }}</BaseTableCell>
    <BaseTableCell :variant="'with_background'" :alignment="'right'">€{{ pastOrder.amount }}</BaseTableCell>
    <BaseTableCell :variant="'with_background'">{{ pastOrder.supplier }}</BaseTableCell>
    <BaseTableCell :variant="'with_background'">
      <BaseBadge :variant="pastOrder.status.variant">{{ pastOrder.status.text }}</BaseBadge>
    </BaseTableCell>
  </BaseTableRow>
</BaseTable>
```

As you can see, the variant prop is also required by the table rows and cells. The table rows simply fill a default `<slot></slot>` in BaseTable.vue. I would love to pass the variant property to the items that are rendered in that slot, so that I would only have to change the variant on BaseTable to change it on all subcomponents. Is this possible? Existing questions seem to discuss the usage of slot properties in the parent component, but then I would still have to add it to every cell whenever I create a table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible, but not straightforward. You'll need to parse vnodes from slot in render function and add custom props, which is legit but undocumented technique.. Consider rewriting css so the style affected by with_background from BaseTable would affect nested components

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the following is probably currently the best option:

```
<BaseTable :variant="'with_background'" v-slot="{ variant }" :columns="[{ name: 'Datum' }, { name: 'Bedrag', alignment: 'right' }, { name: 'Verkoper' }, { name: 'Status' }]">
  <BaseTableRow v-for="(pastOrder, index) in pastOrders" :key="index" :variant="variant">
    <BaseTableCell :variant="variant">{{ pastOrder.date }}</BaseTableCell>
    <BaseTableCell :variant="variant" :alignment="'right'">€{{ pastOrder.amount }}</BaseTableCell>
    <BaseTableCell :variant="variant">{{ pastOrder.supplier }}</BaseTableCell>
    <BaseTableCell :variant="variant">
      <BaseBadge :variant="pastOrder.status.variant">{{ pastOrder.status.text }}</BaseBadge>
    </BaseTableCell>
  </BaseTableRow>
</BaseTable>
```

And then in the underlying components, I use `<slot :variant="variant"></slot>` to pass it onto the rows and cells. I do still wonder if that is possible without specifying :variant="variant" on every cell in the parent component every time I use this table..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).